# Pycharm cannot finish updating skeletons

Tags: ssh, pycharm, ssh-tunnel

I'm newly moving from a Linux working environment to Windows, and I'm mainly using local port forwarding+Pycharm to run my python code on a server that is double-hop from my laptop.

I am able to establish the ssh tunnel through Windows cmd or MobaXterm local terminal or MobaXterm tunneling tool. I works fine on my Pycharm, when I check it from tools/deployment/configuration/test connection, and I can also see the files in remote server. But every time I start my Pycharm, it shows two background process, "updating python interpreter" and "updating pycharm helper", and the precess bar simply do not show any moving on! And I cannot run python on remote server, because Pycharm says I lack python helper.

And most wired, when it is running these two precess, my terminal for local port forwarding freezes, and I cannot type in commands in the jump server. And when I try to recheck the connection, it turns out that connection fails.

My ssh tunneling+pycharm deployment used to work fine in my Ubuntu. Thanks anybody who can shed light on my confusion!

Comment: How do you setup your interpreter in PyCharm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, thanks everyone, I have solved this problem.

The reason is simple, but I did not notice that the ~/.pycharm_helper 's size is actually changing in the process, while the GUI bar may be not moving.

So it is due to my double-hop inconvenience, and the low Internet speed. I left it in dorm for a whole night out, and it comes out just fine.